# What am I supposed to do with this generated DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I used Entity's code generation tool on my database which gave me the context

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace LRVault.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class LRC_VAULTEntities : DbContext
    {
        public LRC_VAULTEntities()
            : base("name=LRC_VAULTEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I expected to be able to immediately use it like

```
var context = new LRC_VAULTENtities();
context.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(new Post() { ... });
context.Posts.SubmitChanges();
```

however there is no `Posts` property after I create an instance of `RC_VAULTENtities`. So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Looks like a typo between `LRC_VAULTEntities` and `LRC_VAULTENtities` as the code shows that `Posts` property exists in the DbContext

Comment: @Nkosi, no that's not the issue

Comment: @DeadlyNicotine Well, there's a typo somewhere - since this isn't necessarily related to EF at all. You've explicitly declared `Posts` as a property, so you're almost definitely referencing the wrong class.

Comment: @Rob I did "Go to definition" on my instance of it and that brought me to the class I pasted above

Comment: if you just try to instantiate the context and run a debug session do you get any errors?  Are there any properties available off context?

Comment: Why do you have a throw exception in OnModelCreating? Also you're talking about edit time or execution time ?

Comment: @H.Herzl talking about edit time and this is an auto-generated file

Comment: Maybe you have a conflict with the version of EF and that's the reason you can get access to instance's properties

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Base` class and add references to your projects so that you can call `dbContext` anywhere you want.

```
public class Base
    {
        protected internal LRC_VAULTEntities dbContext;

        public Base()
        {
            dbContext = new LRC_VAULTEntities ();
        }
    }
```